# Two developer certificates on a Mac

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use two iOS developer certificates on one Mac ?
Is there something special to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Nothing specific you have to do.

Comment: And the app will choose automatically the good certificate to use ?

Comment: No, you have application settings for that. Developer certificate is connected with a provisioning profile which is connected with an application id. The same thing you have to do when switching between Developer and Distributor certificates.